# Difference in the meaning of appealed and attracted to

Tags: difference

I have a question about the differences and correct use of appeal and attracted to. I know that attracted is usually used in a physical manner. But if I want to say, that a particular thing has always fascinated me, is then appealed the right choice?

**Example** The complexity of economics has always appealed to me.

Or should I even use fascinated me?

Comment: Have you checked out the dictionary meanings and usage examples of the alternatives? Whether something *appeals*, *attracts*, *fascinates* or another is known only to you and depends on what you really wants to say. You "know that attracted is usually used in a physical manner" from what source?

Comment: @Kris Before asking this question I've searched the web. In a English forum, someone has explained "attracted to" is used in combination with a person

Comment: If you've searched the web before you asked the question, you should at least include a summary of what you found (or didn't find). That way, everyone else doesn't have to go through the same fruitless searches to find you an answer, and we get a better idea of how much you're actually trying to solve your problem, as opposed to coming here as an initial response.

Answer (score 2):

"Appeal," "attract," and "fascinate" can all be used outside of physical contexts. The key to deciding which of the three to use is just a matter of exactly what you want to convey as the three words *are* subtly different.

"Fascinate" stands apart from "appeal" and "attract" as it describes curiosity and is often used in an intellectual context such as, "My mind has always been fascinated by the complexity of economics."

"Attract" tends to describe a more emotional experience, such as, "There is something about economics, my first love, that has always attracted me."

"Appeal" is the most generic of the three and does not carry much in terms of connotations, but it is consequently also the one with the least descriptive power.

Comment: +1 for great answer... I made a few edits to your formatting.